# java cumulative sum scanner method printf

Tags: java

I am new to java and having issues with my first project. I can't seem to get the variables in the correct scope and am unsure about the scanner methods. If anyone can help me with making it work it would be very helpful, thank you!

Create a new program called `LetterGrade`. Prompt the user to enter their name.
Create a method called `calculateAvg()`. Method should use a cumulative sum algorithm to prompt the user to enter 3 scores and calculate the average. Then, return that value to main.
Once the average is returned, Print the student's name and their average using `printf()` command. Create another method called `printLetter()`. Method should pass a parameter (average grade).

Use `if` … `else` `if` … `else` statements to print whether the student has an ‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’, or ‘F’ average grade.
Grade Scale:

90-100 - A

80-89 - B

70-79 - C

60-69 - D

0-59 - F

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LetterGrade {

  private static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program will calculate 3 scores to find the");
    System.out.println("average score and letter grade.");
    System.out.println();
     
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String name = console.nextLine();
    final double total = calculateAverage();
    System.out.printf("Name:  %s/nAverage: %f",name, total);
  }
    
  public static double calculateAverage()  {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
       System.out.print("Please enter score #" + i + ": ");
       double next = console.nextDouble();
       sum += next;
       double total = (sum / 3);
      return total; 
    }
    return total;
  }

  public static double printLetter(int total) {
    double total = console.nextDouble();
    if (total < 60) {
        System.out.print("You're grade is an F."); 
    } else if (total < 70) {
      System.out.print("You're grade is a D.");  
    } else if (total < 80) {
      System.out.print("You're grade is a C.");  
    } else if (total < 90) {
      System.out.print("You're grade is a B.");  
    } else if (total <= 100) {
      System.out.print("You're grade is an A.");  
    } else {
      System.out.print("You have input an invalid number.");  
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: The last two statements within `calculateAverage`'s loop are at the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static double calculateAverage()  {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       System.out.print("Please enter score #" + (i+1) + ": ");
       double next = console.nextDouble();
       sum += next;
    }
    double total = (sum / 3);
    return total; 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LetterGrade{
 private static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program will calculate 3 scores to find the");
    System.out.println("average score and letter grade.");
    System.out.println();
     
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String name = console.nextLine();
    final double total = calculateAverage();
    System.out.printf("Name:  %s/nAverage: %f",name, total);
    printLetter(total);
  }
    
 public static double calculateAverage() {
  double sum = 0.0;
  double total = 0.0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     System.out.print("Please enter score #" + i + ": ");
     double next = console.nextDouble();
     sum += next;
  }
  total = (sum / 3);
  return total;
}
 
public static void printLetter(double total){
     if (total < 60) {
        System.out.print("You're grade is an F."); 
     }
     else if (total < 70){
        System.out.print("You're grade is a D.");  
     }
     else if (total < 80){
        System.out.print("You're grade is a C.");  
     }
     else if (total < 90){
        System.out.print("You're grade is a B.");  
     }
     else if (total <= 100){
        System.out.print("You're grade is an A.");  
     }
     else{
        System.out.print("You have input an invalid number.");  
     }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is that your for statement:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     System.out.print("Please enter score #" + i + "? ");
     double next = console.nextDouble();
     sum += next;
     double total = (sum / 3);
     return total;
}
```

does, not actually "loop" since you return during the very first iteration from it.

You probably want to move the last two lines where you calculate the total outside of it.

---

Other than that there were a few minor typos:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class LetterGrade {
    private static final int NUM_SCORES = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("This program will calculate the average from %d scores and give you a letter grade.%n%n",
                NUM_SCORES);
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            double average = calculateAverage(scanner);
            System.out.printf("%nReport:%n");
            System.out.printf("Name: %s%nAverage: %.2f%n", name, average);
            printLetterGrade(average);
        }
    }

    private static double calculateAverage(Scanner scanner) {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_SCORES; i++) {
            double next = getDoubleInput(scanner, String.format("Please enter score #%d: ", i), 0, 100);
            total += next;
        }
        return total / NUM_SCORES;
    }

    private static void printLetterGrade(double average) {
        if (average < 60) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is a F.");
        } else if (average < 70) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is a D.");
        } else if (average < 80) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is a C.");
        } else if (average < 90) {
            System.out.println("Your grade is a B.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your grade is an A.");
        }
    }

    private static double getDoubleInput(Scanner scanner, String prompt, double minValue, double maxValue) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        double validDouble = -1;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                validDouble = scanner.nextDouble();
                if (validDouble >= minValue && validDouble <= maxValue) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("Error: Please enter a double between %.0f and %.0f inclusive%n", minValue,
                            maxValue);
                    System.out.print(prompt);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.printf("Error: Please enter a double between %.0f and %.0f inclusive%n", minValue, maxValue);
                System.out.print(prompt);
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
        return validDouble;
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
This program will calculate the average from 3 scores and give you a letter grade.

Enter your name: Megan
Please enter score #1: -100
Error: Please enter a double between 0 and 100 inclusive
Please enter score #1: 105
Error: Please enter a double between 0 and 100 inclusive
Please enter score #1: 99
Please enter score #2: 98
Please enter score #3: 100

Report:
Name: Megan
Average: 99.00
Your grade is an A.
```

Try it out **[here](https://repl.it/repls/BossyTemptingUpgrades#Main.java)**.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is with your foor loop which with every iteration it reset its value. you can also write much simple code as below:

```
public static double calculateAverage() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("Please enter score #" + i + ": ");
        sum += console.nextDouble();
    }
    return (sum / 3);
}
```